# Neo4j MERGE constraint violation on non-constraint property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The issue I'm having is similar to this issue [Cypher 'Node Already Exists' issue with MERGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381968/cypher-node-already-exists-issue-with-merge), but it doesn't look like my constraint (`id`) is being violated. Instead, I'm getting an error about another property which shouldn't be a constraint at all. I'm using apoc to connect to a mongo db and have verified that the mongo db is okay. This is my query:

```
CALL apoc.mongodb.get('mongodb://[HOSTNAME]:[PORT],'dbname','tablename',null,true) YIELD value as elt
MERGE (e:TableElements {id : elt.pid})
ON MATCH SET 
    e.symbol = elt.sym,
    e.electron_cfg = elt.el
ON CREATE SET 
    e.atomic_number = elt.num,
    e.symbol = elt.sym,
    e.electron_cfg = elt.el,
    e.atomic_weight = elt.weight,
    e.name = elt.name;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Node(1) already exists with label `TableElements` and property `name` = 'HYDROGEN'
```

All issues with duplicate elements aside, how is it possible that I'm getting a constraint violation on a property that I haven't identified as a constraint? My understanding of MERGE is that it merges only on the properties specified in the merge clause which I think just consists of all nodes with property `id` matching the incoming `elt.pid` and I've already verified that there aren't any duplicate `elt.pid`s, so I'm not sure what could be happening.

Comment: Are you sure `db.indexes()` doesn't return a unique constraint on :TableElements(name) ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Is that a mongo query? I'm rather new to both, but it doesn't seem to be a cypher query and I'm not sure how a constraint on the mongodb would influence setting properties in neo